# YouTube Live Analytics (views, total watch time)

Tags: youtube-api

I need to get metrics (primarily total live views and total/avg live view duration) for YouTube LIVE events.  I'm having trouble with both v2 and v3 APIs.

I can schedule and stream through the API fine, and I'd like to pull the analytics as soon as the broadcast ends to roll up some reports.

**Question**

How can I get total or average live view duration from the v3 API?

Or, how can I properly query the v2 reports API for Live events to get non-zero data back?

**More Details On Current Attempts**

Here are the types of queries I've tried:

*YouTube v3 API:*

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?
    id={live_video_id}&
    part={"statistics,liveStreamingDetails"}&
    access_token={access_token}

{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "...",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "...",
   "id": "..",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "38",
    "likeCount": "1",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "0"
   },
   "liveStreamingDetails": {
    "actualStartTime": "2018-10-11T12:01:23.000Z",
    "actualEndTime": "2018-10-11T14:00:12.000Z",
    "scheduledStartTime": "2018-10-11T12:00:00.000Z",
    "scheduledEndTime": "2018-10-11T14:00:00.000Z"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I can get statistics.viewCount count here, but there's no way to get the avg/total time watched.

*YouTube v2 Reports API:*

```
https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?
    startDate={"2017-01-01"}&
    endDate={time.Now().Add(24*time.Hour).Format("YYYY-MM-DD")}&
    filters={"video==" + live_video_id}&
    metrics={"views,estimatedMinutesWatched"}&
    ids={"channel==MINE"}&
    access_token={accessToken}

{
  "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "views",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "estimatedMinutesWatched",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      0,
      0
    ]
  ]
}
```

This query would seem to give the metrics I need, but it's all 0s, even when v3 returns non-zero views.

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: There really aren't any logs per se.  If you notice above, I gave a sample post pseudocode and response (with access tokens and ids redacted).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** *YouTube Reports API v2 doesn't update the metrics quite often for less popular live streams.*

#### This is how I reached this conclusion...

I fetched the `views, estimatedMinutesWatched` of an old video from my channel. While both these APIs worked, the view count returned by the *YouTube Reports API v2* was not accurate and was lagging behind the *YouTube Data API v3*.

Next, I ran a Livestream (unlisted) and engaged on the stream with a few other accounts. None of these engagements (like, subscribe, views) was shown in the *Reports API v2* nor in YouTube Studio Analytics. This proves that the `"rows": [[0,0]]` returned by *YouTube Reports API v2* is completely normal. But surprisingly, the *Data API v3* did return the correct metrics as you pointed out.

**For live streams with large audience and engagement, the Reports API may work perfectly fine.**

Since the *Data API* doesn't provide watch times of any sort, your best bet would be to use both these APIs in conjunction, *Data API v3* to fetch the basic metrics like `views, likes,..` and the *Reports API v2* for more sophisticated metrics.

**Tip:** If you are interested in displaying the live stream metrics later on, you can use the [`dimension=liveOrOnDemand`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/dimensions#Playback_Detail_Dimensions) parameter and filter the metrics to the `LIVE` stream alone.